# Form going off of page

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to style a form using, but when I put in the margin for the left and right (mx-4), it is only add the margin on the left side and on the right side it's going off of the page.

```
export default function TextArea() {
  return (
      <div className="w-full mt-1 ">
        <p className="text-purple-800 font-medium px-4 py-1">
          What are you thinking?
        </p>
        <textarea
            rows={4}
            name="comment"
            id="comment"
            className="w-full sm:w-auto md:w-2/3 mx-4 h-96 rounded-md border-white sm:text-md placeholder-gray-300 text-black"
            placeholder="Type your idea here..."
        
        />
      </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using full width `w-full` for the div also the same thing for text area.

Here when you give `w-full` it will take the full with of the parent. Here Div is taking full width of its parent and text area is taking the width of div. Here you need to check the div's parent and set the correct width to it.

I believe `mx-4` is being applied at the other end of the text area. You can inspect and see this in your browser

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to `w-full`. The class `w-full` on the parent div is causing the `form` to take up the full width of its parent container.

Change it to `mx-auto`

Change this

```
<div className="w-full mt-1 ">
```

to

```
<div className="mx-auto mt-1">
```